# MouseEnter event in Winform ElementHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, elementhost

I have a Winform with an elementHost in it to contain a WPF UserControl. What I need, is to do something when the mouse enters the elementHost, not the child. I was trying to use MouseEnter event in the elementHost but it does not exists. Is there any chance I can do this? Or is it just not possible? It´s curious to not have mouse events on them.

This are all the events I have:

[image]

And if I want to do it programatically I just dont have any MouseEvent:

[image]

Comment: It exists but it is hidden.  Because it can never work, the WPF element gets the mouse messages.

Comment: I tried converting the elementhost to control. Then i create the event.  I succeded, but it never fires. Seems the only way is q you say. Catching the mouse enter in the elementhost child (usercontrol) directly.

Answer (score 3):

`MouseEnter` event located in `HostContainer` of elementHost,for detect when mouse enter try following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            elementHost1.HostContainer.MouseEnter += new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(HostContainer_MouseEnter);
        }
        void HostContainer_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse entered");
        }

    }
```